# How to create a card with 2 columns in 3:1 width ratio in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, grid

I'm trying to create a card which can have 2 columns which are in a 3:1 width ratio. The catch is that this card has to have dynamic height according to its contents.
Something like this:
[card that i'm trying to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/letq9.png)
This what I have right now:
[what I have right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zXYg.png)
The white space on the top and bottom of the red column needs to also be red.

This is my code:

```
Card(
      elevation: 2,
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 0, left: 10, right: 10),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Flexible(
            flex: 3,
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 8.0,
              ),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  TimelineTile(
                    alignment: TimelineAlign.start,
                    isFirst: true,
                    afterLineStyle: const LineStyle(color: TruckerAppTheme.grey, thickness: 2),
                    indicatorStyle:
                        IndicatorStyle(color: Colors.white, padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0), iconStyle: IconStyle(fontSize: 28, iconData: Icons.location_on_rounded, color: TruckerAppTheme.grey)),
                    endChild: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 8, 0, 0),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                              // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.65,
                              child: Text(widget.load.pickupCity != null ? "${widget.load.pickupCity}, ${widget.load.pickupState}" : "${widget.load.pickupState}",
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.visible, style: TruckerAppTheme.locationText)),
                          SizedBox(
                              // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
                              child: Text(DateFormat('dd-MMM-yy').format(DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').parse(widget.load.pickupTimeStamp!)).toString(),
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, style: TruckerAppTheme.bodyNormalSmall)),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TimelineTile(
                    alignment: TimelineAlign.start,
                    isLast: true,
                    beforeLineStyle: const LineStyle(color: TruckerAppTheme.grey, thickness: 2),
                    indicatorStyle:
                        IndicatorStyle(color: Colors.white, padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0), iconStyle: IconStyle(fontSize: 28, iconData: Icons.flag_rounded, color: TruckerAppTheme.grey)),
                    endChild: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 8, 0, (widget.load.dropTimeStamp != null) ? 0 : 7),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                              //  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
                              child: Text(widget.load.dropCity != null ? "${widget.load.dropCity}, ${widget.load.dropState}" : "${widget.load.dropState}",
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.visible, style: TruckerAppTheme.locationText)),
                          (widget.load.dropTimeStamp != null)
                              ? Text(DateFormat('dd-MMM-yy').format(DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').parse(widget.load.dropTimeStamp!)).toString(),
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, style: TruckerAppTheme.bodyNormalSmall)
                              : Container(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      widget.load.materialType == ""
                          ? Flexible(
                              child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                              child: Text(
                                "${widget.load.loadWeight} ${widget.load.loadUnits.toString()[0] + widget.load.loadUnits.toString().substring(1).toLowerCase()} • ${VehicleTypeMapping().vehicleTypeMapping[widget.load.vehicleType!]!.value}",
                                style: TruckerAppTheme.quantityText,
                              ),
                            ))
                          : Flexible(
                              child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                              child: Text(
                                "${widget.load.loadWeight} ${widget.load.loadUnits.toString()[0] + widget.load.loadUnits.toString().substring(1).toLowerCase()} • ${widget.load.materialType} • ${VehicleTypeMapping().vehicleTypeMapping[widget.load.vehicleType!]!.value}",
                                style: TruckerAppTheme.quantityText,
                              ),
                            )),
                      // const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, color: Colors.grey)
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8, top: 8, right: 8, left: 8),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 0, top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 1),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: TruckerAppTheme.primaryColor.withOpacity(0.5), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0)),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Price",
                    style: TruckerAppTheme.quantityText,
                  ),
                  widget.load.perTonneAmount == null
                      ? Text(
                          "Pending",
                          style: TruckerAppTheme.pricePendingText,
                        )
                      : Text(
                          "₹ ${widget.load.perTonneAmount} Per Tonne",
                          style: TruckerAppTheme.pricePendingText,
                        ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 40,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Bid Now",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    )
```

I have tried using Intrinsic Height, Expanded, etc. but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

way 1.    try to sizedbox widget

```
testWidget(BuildContext context) {
        return Card(
          elevation: 2,
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 0, left: 10, right: 10),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                color: Colors.amber,
              )),
              SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
                height: 100,
                child: Flexible(
                    child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                )),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
```

Comment: That didn't work. It gives the same result as before and an exception: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget. The ParentDataWidget Flexible(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.

Usually, this means that the Flexible widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Flexible widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Flexible is currently placed inside a SizedBox widget.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and its working as expected. Make sure you have zero margin for the `Container`.

```
          Card(
              elevation: 2,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 3,
                    fit: FlexFit.tight,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: const [
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                            child: Text('ITEM!'),
                          ),],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 1,
                    fit: FlexFit.tight,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.7),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: const [
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                            child: Text('ITEM!'),
                          ),
                     ...
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ))
```

Comment: Hi Soliev, it still doesnt work. If the contents in the first column are a lot, I still see the white areas at the top and below the 2nd column.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a custom clipper as below code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Stack(
  children: [
    Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 40,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.red,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
    ),
    ClipPath(
      clipper: PromoCustomClipper(),
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 40,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 15, right: 125),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text('Content dynamic height'),
              const SizedBox(height: 15),
              Text('Content description')
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

}

// custom clipper class

```
class PromoCustomClipper extends CustomClipper<Path>{
@override
  getClip(Size size) {
  var path = Path();
  path.lineTo(0, 0);
  path.lineTo(0, size.height);
  path.lineTo(230, size.height);
  path.lineTo(230, 0);
  return path;
```

}

@override

bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper oldClipper) {

return false;

}

}

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This doesn't work however as the red part's height is much smaller than the grey part's height